# Excel counting issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I'm working on [this example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nsbzWkHkfhy5CX5QAYTaAEfYdaqkLgg4n4kN-JwuVKY/edit?usp=sharing) and I'm having trouble.

Specifically, I want to know how many different people may be scoring the same result. I need to know the function because it needs to be applied on a much, much larger scale.

For example, persons c, d, and e, all had total scores of 23. Persons f and g both had total scores of 26. Person a had a total score of 75. I need to show that 3 people scored 23, 2 people scored 26, and 1 scored 75.

I've linked the sheet I'm playing around in to work out the function, so any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: FYI That link tells me I need to ask for permission to open the document

Comment: Why the uni decided links should only be accessible by other uni members, I will never know. Changed now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php).

Use `=COUNTIF(*range*, *value*)`

Comment: I'm aware of the countif function, am not sure if this is what I need/am having trying applying it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked out an adequate work-around.
Sorted column a alphabetically and used a "=IF(A45=A44,"",SUMIF($A$3:$A$65,A45,$B$3:$B$65))" to avoid repeating the same total being printed, over and over, for all players, allowing me to use =UNIQUE and then =COUNTIF to identify the unique scores and how many people scored particular scores.
Didn't really want to sort, but it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

No need to sort the data with this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,$A3)<>1,"",SUMIF($A$3:$A$65,$A3,$B$3:$B$65))
```

The formula shows the total score for each player only the first time that a player appears in column `A`. The formula assumes your data is in range `$A$3:$B$65` *(change as needed)*.

*Note the missing* `$` *in* `COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,$A3)`

To try, just enter the formula in cell `C3` *(or any other column at row 3)* and copy down to the last row of your data.